# Locking iOS Camera Exposure Crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturedevice, camera-api

I have the following code:

```
-(void) startCameraCapture {
    // start capturing frames
    // Create the AVCapture Session
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // create a preview layer to show the output from the camera
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    // Specify that the video should be stretched to fill the layer’s bounds.
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;

    //previewView.frame = CGRectMake(126.0, 164.0, 64.0, 75.0);


    previewLayer.frame = previewView.frame;
    [previewView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    // Get the default camera device
    AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // get the current settings
    [appDelegate loadSettings];
    [session startRunning];     
}
```

Is there a way I can lock the exposure of a camera device to only allow the screen to adjust to a certain brightness?

Sorry if I am not asking this right.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried adding:

```
[camera setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMake(1,1) ISO:100 completionHandler:nil];
```

but that only results in the app crashing at that line.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:

Comment: When I try the `setExposureModeCustomWithDuration` method call I get an error. I am not sure what I should call that on? My AVCaptureDevice?

Comment: @Tukajo Did you ever figure this out? I am getting the same problem

Comment: No I got moved onto a different project sorry!

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's doc:

An `NSGenericException` exception is thrown if this method is invoked without first obtaining exclusive access to the receiver using `lockForConfiguration`:.

So add this line in front:

```
[camera lockForConfiguration:nil];
```

Comment: I still get the app freezing `[camera setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMake(1,1) ISO:100 completionHandler:nil];` even after adding the code above.